# Is it possible to share SPI pins between two TFT displays and AD9850 signal generator?

Tags: arduino, spi

This one is a little tricky, because the AD9850 does not have a CS pin.. the TFT displays do. So sharing the pins (except CS of course) between the displays seems straight-forward, but how can we use the AD9850 at the same time: Do we need to use separate pins for AD9850 with bit-banging, or is it possible to share all three devices on the same pins somehow?

Comment: With external buffer, such as 74x245/74x244 it's easy to achieve. I mean to have a CS available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the AD9850 does not really have an SPI interface, but the timing of the serial interface does seem to be compatible, so you may be able to use an SPI master to write to the AD9850. However, another pin (FQ_UD) is required to update the data.

The main problem is, as you already suggested, that it does not have a chip select (CS) input. This means that all data on the serial interface will be clocked by the AD9850. The behavior for parallel mode is clearly documented in the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad9850.pdf):

> In the parallel load mode, the register is loaded via an 8-bit bus;
> the full 40-bit word requires five iterations of the 8-bit word. The W_CLK and FQ_UD signals are used to address and load the registers. The rising edge of FQ_UD loads the (up to) 40-bit control data-word into the device and resets the address pointer to the first register. Subsequent W_CLK rising edges load the 8-bit data on words [7:0] and move the pointer to the next register. **After *five* loads, W_CLK edges are ignored until either a reset or an FQ_UD rising edge resets the address pointer to the first register.**

According to my interpretation, this means that if you would write 10 bytes to it, the first 5 bytes are stored (and will be "activated" using the `FQ_UD` signal), and the last 5 bytes are ignored. This is problematic in your use case.

For serial mode, the exact behavior is slightly less documented, but it seems to be approximately the same:

> In serial load mode, subsequent rising edges of W_CLK shift the 1-bit data on Pin 25 (D7) through the 40 bits of programming information. **After 40 bits are shifted through, an FQ_UD pulse is required to update the output frequency (or phase).**

**So what can you do?**

- The best solution would be to use a dedicated interface for the AD9850. This would require 3 pins and give you full control over all devices. I ***highly*** recommend this if you have the possibility to do this (that is, if you have control over the hardware and enough free pins available).
- If you only need to write to the AD9850 during startup, you could probably make it work by first configuring the AD9850 (with the chip selects for the TFT displays disabled) and then configuring the displays (while never toggling FQ_UD, so the configuration of the AD9850 will not be updated anymore). This depends on your specific use case and I doubt it will be the case.
- I also was wondering if you could "flush" invalid data input to the AD9850 by toggling FQ_UD and then immediately writing the correct configuration afterwards. However, this seems dangerous because there are certain control codes that may brick the device:

  > There are specific control codes, used for factory test purposes, that render the AD9850 temporarily inoperable. The user must take deliberate precaution to avoid inputting the codes listed in Table II.
  > If you can guarantee there will be no invalid codes and you can accept invalid configurations for a short time, this is something you could consider, but I think it's asking for troubles.

NB: My first advice would be to do some tests with the AD9850 to confirm if my interpretation of the datasheet is correct. It's quite common for serial interfaces to be implemented with a shift register, in which case only the **last** 40 bits will be used (instead of the first 40 bits). IMHO, the datasheet does not explicitly confirm or deny this. If it *does* use the last 40 bits, it would be quite trivial to share the pins.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extensive answer, wovano. I do have control over the hardware, so it seems like using a dedicated interface seems the most reasonable way to proceed. Since the displays are SPI, then if I use an Arduino Nano 3 then I assume the displays would get the SPI pins (D11=MOSI, D12=MISO, D13=SCK, D4+D5=CS) and I would use some regular pins for AD9850 (D8=W_CLK, D9=FQ_UD, D6=DATA, D5=RESET), or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @JohnHawthorne, correct. I don't know all the Arduino pins, but what you wrote in the comment makes sense and seems the right approach to me.

Comment: With external buffer, such as 74x245/74x244 it's easy to achieve. I mean to have a CS available.